# Class not found using namspace in PHP

Tags: php

I am using namespace in my php application, but when i load the page it show me error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Route\Router' not found in >C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in >C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php on line 10

```
        <?php

        require_once 'routes/Router.php';

        use Route\Router;

        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $router = new Router($request);
        $router->get('/', 'view/index');
        $router->get('post', 'view/auth/login');
```

...

```
        <?php

        namespace Route;

        class Router
        {
            private $request;

            function __construct($request)
            {
                $this->request = $request;
            }

            public function get($route, $file)
            {
                $uri = trim($this->request, "/");
                $uri = explode("/", $uri);
                if ($uri[0] == trim($route, "/")) {
                    array_shift($uri);
                    $args = $uri;
                    require $file . '.php';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I noticed that the namespace is `Route`, while your path is `routes`

Comment: Thanku for your precious time, but i found it already.